# C# : Use PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority> to implement Max Heap

Tags: c#, binary-tree

C# has the **PriorityQueue**<TElement,TPriority> Class in **.NET 6**. By default, this **PriorityQueue** is a **Min Heap**.

Now, I want to use PriorityQueue to implement **Max Heap** by adding my own **Compare**() method. But, maybe, due to some bugs, it still works as a **Min Heap**.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Max_Heap : IComparer<int>{
    
     public int Compare(int first, int second)
     {
        if (first == second) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (first > second) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Here is my Max Heap:");

    PriorityQueue<string, int> queue = new PriorityQueue<string, int>();

    queue.Enqueue("Item A", 0);
    queue.Enqueue("Item B", 60);
    queue.Enqueue("Item C", 45);
    queue.Enqueue("Item D", 1);

    while (queue.TryDequeue(out string item, out int priority))
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Popped Item : {item}. Priority Was : {priority}");
    }

  }
}
```

Please tell me how I can fix this code to make it behave as a **Max Heap**.

==============================

**Updated**: I figured out where the bug is. When I instantiate the PriorityQueue, I must also instantiate an instance of the class that contains the Compare() method and pass it to the constructor of
the PriorityQueue as follow:

```
PriorityQueue<string, int> queue = new PriorityQueue<string, int>(new Max_Heap());
```

This new code will work as I have tested it.

Comment: `new Max_Heap()` is not a name of a class it is a new instance of class implementing `IComparable`

Comment: @GuruStron, OK. I will update the post.